# Need a Warning within Access when NumLock is Off

Tags: vba, ms-access

One of my database forms was not working properly. It took me a while before I realised that NumLock was off. There are procedures to reverse the process when NumLock is turned off by pressing the key but it might not be just accidental pressing of the key that turns off NumLock. In MS Access, at the bottom right of the window you get "NUM LOCK" if it's on, nothing if it's off. Is there a way, say in vba, to warn if the words "NUM LOCK" do not appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetNumlock = CBool(GetKeyState(vbKeyNumlock) And 1)
```

Example:

```
If (CBool(GetKeyState(vbKeyNumlock) And 1) = True
    MsgBox "NumLock is on." 
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. Where do I put this procedure?

Comment: This just gives you the state of the key.  You have to figure out what to do with it, based on your specific requirements.  I've added an example to my answer.